# when lead converted into opportunity, then Close Date is set to the last day of current fiscal quarter. can we set Close Date to greater than 90 days?

Tags: opportunity, lead-conversion, standard-field, closedate

Opportunity Close Date is automatically set during Lead Conversion, which means that when we convert lead into opportunity, that time Close Date is set to the last day of current fiscal quarter. can we change that automation? means can we set Close Date to greater than 90 days(Today + 90) during Lead Conversion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a before save or after save flow or trigger to set the close date to whatever you'd like. Note that Process Builder and Workflow Rules are deprecated and shouldn't be used.